# What do we call someone who is being dictated to?

Tags: single-word-requests

The one who rules or dictates is dictator, but what do we call the one who is being dictated to? I'm looking for a better match than slave, subservient, etc.
I am trying to find a word that matches a common etymological pattern like:

Interview brings two words:

interviewer- a person who interviews someone, and

interviewee-a person who is interviewed.

Similarly, the one who dictates get 'dictator', so what is the word for the one who is 'dictated by a dictator'

I am looking for a word that is derived from the word 'dictate', if available.

Comment: There is no particular word. _Dictator_ is not a symmetric relation.

Comment: 'dictatee' would be the expected morphological transformation, except that just isn't a word and the semantics doesn't really work ('dictator' is all about the role as a leader, and doesn't say much about their relationship with those they dictate to).

Comment: When someone dictates a letter, the person receiving the dictation is said to 'take' the letter. But we do not, idiomatically, call the person dictating a 'Dictator' in that context.

Comment: @Mitch- Thanks, that’s convincing.

Comment: *Subject?* *Citizen?* *Minion?*

Comment: And there’s always. *admin, secretary, stenographer*...

Comment: Why does this feel like someone's trying to respond to a dissenter on WaPo?

Comment: When a newly joined manager called a stenographer saying he wanted to dictate, he was corrected to use "give a dictation to" and not 'dictate to'. In dictatorial management, the 'dictated' can also be a poor stenographer  :)

Comment: does follower fit?

Comment: oppressor and oppressed works better.

Comment: You could use “dictatee” is a humorous way, e.g. the dictator was convinced of his brilliance as a military strategist; the dictatees  had other thoughts, mostly involving travel to the border and as far as possible beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to say “secretary”, but in this context, with no specific word for this concept, a noun from the past participle will serve (as in many other situations):

> The **dictated**

Now write it down.

Comment: How about "stenographer"?

Comment: @HotLicks — American English. I speak the other variety.

Comment: "dictation secretary" or "audio typist" would be other terms in the other context.

Answer (score 2):

Our word *dictator* comes from a Latin term for a magistrate who was given *temporary* supreme power in an emergency; it means something like *one who speaks*. We don't say that a dictator 'dictates' the people he rules over.

Comment: A Dictator issues dictats.

Comment: Not an answer to OP's question (which I've rendered grammatical).

Comment: Sorry, but I believe I was referring to the other meaning of dictator. As in ruler, not the speaker.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- Thanks for the grammar cleanup!

Answer (score 1):

Were I a dictator, I would regard others as my *subjects*, rather as a king or queen does.

> **Subject:**  one that is placed under authority or control: such as
>
>  **a.** vassal
>
> **b (1):** one subject to a monarch and governed by the monarch's law
>
> **b (2):** one who lives in the territory of, enjoys the protection of, and owes allegiance to a sovereign power or state.

[[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject)

Comment: *Subject* is in the right area, although a constitutional monarch also has subjects, despite not being a dictator.

Answer (score 0):

This was a really long time ago, but it was relevant to me today and I found this answer. If I want someone to transcribe what I am saying I would say that "I am going to give a dictation." But what am I called? This is the closest I got..

DICTION
[ˈdikSH(ə)n]
NOUN
the choice and use of words and phrases in speech or writing:
"Wordsworth campaigned against exaggerated poetic diction"

synonyms: phraseology · phrasing · turn of phrase · choice of words · wording · [more]

the style of enunciation in speaking or singing:
"she began imitating his careful diction"
synonyms: enunciation · articulation · elocution · locution · pronunciation · speech · [more]

Comment: lol ignore me. I was looking at dictation from a different meaning!

Comment: Hello, Jarid. Please delete the answer in that case, if possible.